# Installing OctoberCMS on Azure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure, octobercms

I have created an App Service and SQL Database(created new & blank sql db) on Azure to install OctoberCMS. I have got as far as the Database install page and after inputting my credentials I created earlier when creating the DB and I get an error saying my new database is not blank.

> Database "DatabaseName" is not empty. Please empty the database or specify another database.
>   There is a problem with the specified Database configuration.

I have been playing around with various configuration bits on azure for quite a while now and I'm just tearing my hair out trying to work it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any more info is needed let me know.

Comment: I am not familiar with OctoberCMS (trying an install now) but looking at the docs, it says "When using the SQL Server database engine, you will need to install the group concatenation user-defined aggregate".  Did you do this yet?

Comment: After a little more research, I don't think Azure SQL will be an option because of the user-defined aggregate requirement.  Options include 1) Run MSSQL as an IaaS VM, there you can create a users-defined aggregate or 2) User Azure Database for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install to Azure Web App and Azure Database for MySQL.  High level steps are:

```
 1. Create Azure Web App, ensure App settings are set to use PHP 7.0 or
    higher 
 2. Deploy code through Kudo Zip Deployment (or whatever method you are comfortable)
 3. Create Azure Database for MySQL
 4. Browse to Azure Database for MySQL -> Connection Security
 5.     Click + Add client IP
 6.     Allow Access to Azure Services = ON
 7.     Enforce SSL Connection = DISABLED
 8. Use whatever tool you like to create MySQL DB, I used MySQL Workbench.
 9. Browse to https://<yourwebapp>.azurewebsites.net/install-master/install.php
 10. Use info from Azure Database for MySQL -> Overview to fill in DB values
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file